# BlueImp Jquery File Upload Multiple mobile upload with same name

Tags: jquery, file-upload, mobile-safari, jquery-file-upload, blueimp

I'm having a tremendous issue which has already taken a week of work and no solution.

I'm working with Rails 4.2 and https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload to upload multiple images directly to s3 bucket.

Everything works fine, but when I use it on my iPhone and Safari (everything up-to-date) I take two different photos, both are named automatically by Safari image.jpg. I know this is a Safari "feature" (I'd call it bug) but even in Chrome if I select two different files from different folders with same name it only uploads the first-one.

Example:
folder A --> file a.jpg
folder B --> file a.jpg

I select both (at the same time, one after the other one, drag & drop) but it only uploads the first one!

I want to find a way to overwrite filename if there's more than one with same name, so that I solve Safari and Chrome bugs.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: it's an iOS feature, even Chrome can't upload multiple files with same name on iPhone